# How to make a one to one left outer join?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was wondering, is there a way to make a kind of one to one left outer join:

I need a join that matches say table A with table B, for each record on table A it must search for its pair on table B, but there exists only 1 record that matches that condition, so when it has found its pair on B, it must stop and continue with the next row at table A.

What I have is a simple `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```sql
select * from A left outer join B on A.ID = B.ID order by (NAME) asc
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a one to one relationship defined in the database, or can B contain N records associated with A based on the foreign key?

Comment: What is wrong with your left join ?

Comment: Is a one to one defined relationship Josh

Comment: Hi manitra, for me nothing... but I'm trying to optimized it... (just to learn about it).

Comment: @Randolf: Again, nothing seems to be wrong with your join. The fact that it's one-to-one is simply something defined in the keys, there is no special syntax for a one-to-one join. What you have there should result in a single row for every row in `A`, with the corresponding row in `B` if it exists.

Comment: Thanks Adam :) I just thought mine was wrong and there was another 'optimized way' to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you present in your question is correct. There is no difference in the query for joining on a one-to-one relationship than on a one-to-many.

Answer (score 3):

SQL doesn't work this way. In the first place it does not look at things row-by-row. In the second place what defines the record you want to match on?

Assuming you don't really care which row is selcted, something like this might work:

```
SELECT * 
From tableA
left outer join 
(select b.* from tableb b1
join (Select min(Id) from tableb group by id) b2 on b1.id - b2.id) b
on a.id = b.id
```

BUt it still is pretty iffy that you wil get the records you want when there are multiple records with the id in table b.

Comment: Hi HLGEM, I forget to say that in both cases the identifiers within JOIN condition are unique. Thanks

Comment: -1 for missing the point of the question. You've over-complicating the issue.

Comment: @AdamRobinson I learned something from this answer. Doesn't have to exactly answer the question to be useful